# Screenshot to clipboard by default

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, screen-capture

My muscle memory is very ingrained with <kbd>Cmd + Shift + 4</kbd> to take screen snips, and this has been fine for a while.

However, from now on, I don't need to save my screen snips as files. I need to paste them directly to various places (e.g. online, or in documents).

How do I make <kbd>Cmd + Shift + 4</kbd> save to clipboard instead of files (like Windows with <kbd>Win + Shift + S</kbd>)? My fingers are unable to grasp the concept of <kbd>Cmd + Ctrl + Shift + 4</kbd> (that's just too many keys).

Ideally, and tl;dr, I'd like to swap the functionality of <kbd>Cmd + Shift + 4</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd + Ctrl + Shift + 4</kbd>.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots

You can set them to anything you like, so long as it doesn't conflict with any existing command.

[image: settings, keyboard shortcuts pane]

*Late edit to make this a more comprehensive answer;*

- For any single shot - these are not 'remembered' between shots…
- If you tap  <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>  after your opening key command, the cursor turns into a camera. Clicking on any window will then capture the entire window, plus drop shadow, as above.
- Holding  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  as you click will remove the shadow.
- Holding  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  as you click will send it to clipboard instead of saved as a file.

Since macOS Mojave, many of these defaults can be overridden by using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>  which brings up a user interface with many options, including both screenshot & video screen capture. These can be set to remember between sessions.

[image: Screen shot dialog]

One thing I also discovered a few years ago is that you can still invoke  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>   whilst the screenshot interface is open, so you can capture scenes that otherwise wouldn't be possible.

Comment: How'd you take this SS with shadows? Mine has none https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtkT0.png

Comment: @ankiiiiiii - cmd/shift/4 as usual, but then tap the spacebar . The cursor turns into a camera icon & turns any window you hover over blue. Click your chosen window to get the entire window plus drop-shadow.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Yep, spacebar turns it into window capture mode. If you don't want the shadow while in window capture mode, hold Option when you click.

Comment: I settled on just learning the new, longer shortcut. It was a disaster when I used a friend's macbook. I kept pasting whatever was on his clipboard rather than my screen snip, which landed on Desktop.

Comment: Yeah, there's always something to be said for 'learning to do it the accepted way' :)

Comment: this is great. I've turned the shortcuts for selected area to clipboard and selected area to file around. Since I typically want to use the clipboard one.

Comment: (By default) you can also just hold Option while pressing any screenshot keyboard shortcut to save it to your clipboard

Comment: Ctrl sends it to clipboard, opt removes the drop shadow [as mentioned above] I've added these to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>
2. Select **Options**
3. Select **Clipboard**
4. Exit

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> from then on follows the option set here. Easily change options; no key reprogramming, etc. Ventura, MBP

Comment: that's the correct/best answer imho.